# Setting up routes in RoR v3 with no views, just JavaScript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, routes

This is probably a very simple question. I am new to Rails and have just hit my first major roadblock.
I have two controllers, Groups and MembershipRequests. When someone submits a MembershipRequest, the admin of the Group has the option to accept or deny the request. In my MembershipRequests controller, I have two methods: accept and deny. They both work, but now I'm unsure of dealing with my routes.

This is the relevant part of my routes.rb:

```
resources :groups do
  member do
    get 'members'
    resources :membership_requests do
      member do
        post 'accept'
        post 'deny'
      end
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

Okay, onto my real question: I want to be able to accept and deny requests without an additional page. I want to use JavaScript to use a button on my MembershipRequests index page where the admin can accept or deny the requests.

Here's my erb code for the accept and deny buttons:

`<%= link_to "Accept", :controller => 'membership_requests', :action => 'accept', :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>`

`<%= link_to "Deny", :controller => 'membership_requests', :action => 'deny', :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>`

Clicking either of these links give me the
`No route matches "/groups/1/membership_requests/1/{accept,deny}"`
just like I would expect. But I do not know how to get around this. Thanks!

Comment: what does the controller look like? you probably just want a redirect_to at the end of it so there is no need for a view

Comment: Please use routing helpers provided to you instead of hashes containing `:controller` and `:action` keys for your links.

Comment: To add to Ryan Bigg's answer,  you can use `rake routes` to find out what routes are available. The way you've written links here is Rails 2.x style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, `link_to` should also have `:method => :post` because you're mapping it to a custom (non-RESTful) action (that's just an assumption) and `:remote => true`, to tell rails that this link uses unobtrusive JS.

[This screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) might help, or at least give a starting point.

Oh, and yes. As Ryan suggests, you'd better use something like this:

```
@requests.each do |request|
  link_to "Accept", membership_request_accept_path(request), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :remote => true
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the link to that screencast, that's actually what got me started down this road, but later I could not find it! Also, thank you for the code, which really helped too.